# Fetch rss with php - Conditional for Enclosured image and not Enclosured

Tags: php, xml, rss, fetch

I'm working on a project and it's something new for me. I'll need to fetch rss content from websites, and display Descripion, Title and Images (Thumbnails). Right now i've noticed that some feeds show thumbnails as Enclosure tag and some others dont. right now i have the code for both, but i need to understand how i can create a conditional like:

If the rss returns enclosure image { Do something }
Else { get the common thumb }

Here follow the code that grab the images:

ENCLOSURE TAG IMAGE:

```
if ($enclosure = $block->get_enclosure())
{
echo "<img src=\"" . $enclosure->get_link() . "\">";
}
```

NOT ENCLOSURE:

```
if ($enclosure = $block->get_enclosure())
{
    echo '<img src="'.$enclosure->get_thumbnail().'" title="'.$block->get_title().'" width="200" height="200">';
}
```

=================================================================================================

PS: If we look at both codes they're almost the same, the difference are get_thumbnail and get_link.

Is there a way i can create a conditional to use the correct code and always shows the thumbnail?

Thanks everyone in advance!

**EDITED**

Here is the full code i have right now:

```
include_once(ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php');
if(function_exists('fetch_feed')) {
$feed = fetch_feed('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/africa/rss.xml'); // this is the external     website's RSS feed URL
if (!is_wp_error($feed)) : $feed->init();
$feed->set_output_encoding('UTF-8'); // this is the encoding parameter, and can be left unchanged in almost every case
$feed->handle_content_type(); // this double-checks the encoding type
$feed->set_cache_duration(21600); // 21,600 seconds is six hours
$feed->handle_content_type();
$limit = $feed->get_item_quantity(18); // fetches the 18 most recent RSS feed stories
$items = $feed->get_items(0, $limit); // this sets the limit and array for parsing the feed
endif;
}

$blocks = array_slice($items, 0, 3); // Items zero through six will be displayed here
foreach ($blocks as $block) {
//echo $block->get_date("m d Y");
echo '<div class="single">';
if ($enclosure = $block->get_enclosure())
{
    echo '<a href="'.$block->get_link().'" target="_blank"><img class="image_post" src="'.$enclosure->get_link().'" title="'.$block->get_title().'" width="150" height="100"></a>';
}

echo '<div class="description">';

echo '<a href="'.$block->get_link().'" target="_blank"><h3>'. $block->get_title() .'</h3></a>';
echo '<p>'.$block->get_description().'</p>';

echo '</div>';
echo '<div class="clear"></div>';
echo '</div>';  

}
```

And here are the XML pieces with 2 different tags for images:

Using Thumbnails: view-source:http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/africa/rss.xml

Using Enclosure: http://feeds.news24.com/articles/news24/SouthAfrica/rss

Comment: As long as you don't share what `$block` is and also you don't share the XML pieces that show the differences, the answer is that you need to create the appropriate condition - which is kinda moot as you have problems to find it. Tip: Work with/along the differences.

Comment: Hello @hakre, as suggested i've edited the question with the full code, so you can understand what i have, and also updated with both XML using thumbnail and enclosure tags. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way i can create a conditional to use the correct code and always shows the thumbnail?

Sure there is. You've not said in your question what blocks you so I have to assume the reason, but I can imagine multiple.

### Is the reason a decisions with more than two alternations?

You handle the scenario of a feed item having no image or an image already:

```
if ($enclosure = $block->get_enclosure())
{
    echo '<a href="'.$block->get_link().'" target="_blank"><img class="image_post" src="'.$enclosure->get_link().'" title="'.$block->get_title().'" width="150" height="100"></a>';
}
```

With your current scenario there is only one additional alternation which makes it three: if the enclosure is a thumbnail and not a link:

1. No image (no enclosure)
2. Image from link (enclosure with link)
3. Image from thumbnail (enclosure with thumbnail)

And you then don't know how to create a decision of that. This is what basically [else-if](http://php.net/elseif) is for:

```
if (!$enclosure = $block->get_enclosure())
{
    echo "no enclosure: ", "-/-", "\n";
} elseif ($enclosure->get_link()) {
    echo "enclosure link: ", $enclosure->get_link(), "\n";
} elseif ($enclosure->get_thumbnail()) {
    echo "enclosure thumbnail: ", $enclosure->get_thumbnail(), "\n";
}
```

This is basically then doing the output based on that. However if you assign the image URL to a variable, you can decide on the output later on:

```
$image = NULL;
if (!$enclosure = $block->get_enclosure())
{
    // nothing to do
} elseif ($enclosure->get_link()) {
    $image = $enclosure->get_link();
} elseif ($enclosure->get_thumbnail()) {
    $image = $enclosure->get_thumbnail();
}

if (isset($image)) {
    // display image
}
```

And if you then move this more or less complex decision into a function of it's own, it will become even better to read:

```
$image = feed_item_get_image($block);

if (isset($image)) {
    // display image
}
```

This works quite well until the decision becomes even more complex, but this would go out of scope for an answer on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hello @hakre, this worked very great, sorry for my late reply, got some problems to sold, I have only one problem with this code, i just noticed that some Feeds comes with content:encoded, and the image is just inside, how to get that with your conditional?

Comment: Yuo need to differentiate further. So you've got three cases then. move it first into a function then probably functions (so called functional decomposition). If this further grows, refactor that part of the code following object oriented programming principles.